# INSERT IGNORE INTO not working

Tags: php, mysql

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO sobd_voucher_types(voucher_type) VALUES('$voucher_array[$i]')
```

I want to avoid inserting duplicate data.
 **voucher_type** column is unique.
this query is working properly on when i run it on mysql.
but the same query is not when i run from php.
the duplicate data is still getting inserted

Comment: use double qutos `"` to enclose variables, `("$voucher_array[$i]")`

Answer (score 0):

If the duplicate data is inserted, then it means that `voucher_type` column is not unique, because ***`IGNORE`*** only skips errors (not prevents from the duplicates inserts).

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html

> If you use the IGNORE modifier, errors that occur while executing the
>   INSERT statement are ignored. For example, without IGNORE, a row that
>   duplicates an existing UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY value in the table
>   causes a duplicate-key error and the statement is aborted. With
>   IGNORE, the row is discarded and no error occurs. Ignored errors may
>   generate warnings instead, although duplicate-key errors do not.

Comment: The problem is my query is running perfectly fine when i run it on mysql.
If there duplicates it does not add a new row. 
But when i run it with php 
It still enters a new duplicate row

Comment: @DesmondDias Can you show schema of your table? Because it is impossible to solve this problem without all information.